# Can't apply border radius to canvas (html2canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, css

The html div looks fine.

But when I use html2canvas the image displays wrong.

[image]

[image]

Background

```
#ref{
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
    background: url(/assets/refer/bec.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    float: left;
}
```

I use this for rounding

```
.circular {
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
}
```

html2canvas

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("qqq"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  },
  width: 500,
  height: 500
});
```

What am I doing wrong? ty

Comment: Hey railsr! I do have the exact same problem, did you find a solution for that? WOuld be much appreciated! Thank ;)

Comment: @user3877230, hi. I decided not to use canvas.

Comment: Thanks for your response! See you!

Answer (score 4):

As of my knowledge for html2canvas border radius should be half of the width or height at max.In your case it should be max 75.

```
.circular {
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

canvas picks up the border-radius fine. Perhaps your content is not covering the edges so you can't see it. Try making sure your content fills the canvas and covers the corners

Comment: ops. I still have this problem in safari. But in FireFox the image displays properly. In Google Chrome the canvas is not displayed at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a reported bug on html2canvas ([see here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/318)) and a fix was merged into the repo.

If you're using release version 0.4.1, edit `function calculateCurvePoints` as follows:

```
...
blh = borderRadius[3][0],
    blv = borderRadius[3][1];

      var halfHeight = Math.floor(height / 2);
      tlh = tlh > halfHeight ? halfHeight : tlh;
      tlv = tlv > halfHeight ? halfHeight : tlv;
      trh = trh > halfHeight ? halfHeight : trh;
      trv = trv > halfHeight ? halfHeight : trv;
      brh = brh > halfHeight ? halfHeight : brh;
      brv = brv > halfHeight ? halfHeight : brv;
      blh = blh > halfHeight ? halfHeight : blh;
      blv = blv > halfHeight ? halfHeight : blv;

    var topWidth = width - trh,
    rightHeight = height - brv,
...
```

Credit for Grom-S for reporting and resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced problems for ellipse shape while exporting pdf using Html2Canvas, so I was set border-radius as half of (width + height) of shape, so problem solved..